# Does asynchronous message transmission and reception make sense in PSQL protocol?

Tags: haskell, asynchronous

I am trying to understand the following code (taken from https://github.com/zadarnowski/postgresql-wire-protocol) which asynchronously sends and receives PSQL wire protocol messages. I am wondering how and when it would be useful to have this notion of an asynchronous send and receive. If I am getting the responses back on a separate thread, how do I know which request any given response belongs to.

Additionally, if a particular message caused an error, how would I know which message caused that error?

```
module Database.PostgreSQL.Protocol.Client.Connection (
  Frontend
) where

import Control.Concurrent.Chan
import Control.Concurrent.MVar


 data FrontendSession = FrontendSession {
   frontendSendQueue  :: Chan FrontendMessage,
   frontendRecvQueue  :: Chan BackendMessage,
   frontendProcQueue  :: Chan BackendMessageHandler,
   frontendSendThread :: ThreadId,
   frontendRecvThread :: ThreadId,
   frontendProcThread :: ThreadId
 }

 newtype BackendMessageHandler :: Consume (BackendMessage -> IO BackendMessageHandler) | Pass


 beginFrontendSession :: (Int32 -> IO Lazy.ByteString) -> (Lazy.ByteString -> IO ()) -> IO FrontendSession
 beginFrontendSession readData writeData = do
   sendQueue <- newChan
   recvQueue <- newChan
   procQueue <- newChan
   sendThread <- forkIO $ forever $ readChan sendQueue >>= writeData . toLazyByteString . frontendMessage
   recvThread <- forkIO $ forever $ readBackendMessage readData >>= writeChan recvQueue
   procThread <- forkIO $ let getNextMessage h = readChan recvQueue >>= apply h
                              apply (Consume h) m = h m >>= getNextMessage
                              apply (Pass) m = readChan procQueue >>= flip apply m
                           in getNextMessage Pass
   return FrontendSession {
     frontendSendQueue  = sendQueue,
     frontendRecvQueue  = recvQueue,
     frontendProcQueue  = procQueue,
     frontendSendThread = sendThread,
     frontendRecvThread = recvThread
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The library in question appears to be in its very early stages. The file you are asking about doesn't even parse; and after fixing the parse errors doesn't compile. I doubt very much whether it's possible to give serious answers to any question about this codebase for some time yet. Still, I will make an attempt.

> I am wondering how and when it would be useful to have this notion of an asynchronous send and receive. If I am getting the responses back on a separate thread, how do I know which request any given response belongs to.

It's not clear to me that "asynchronous" implies "you must send and receive on separate threads". However, it may imply that doing so is allowed; in which case presumably your two threads will need to be in communication with each other somehow.

> Additionally, if a particular message caused an error, how would I know which message caused that error?

Presumably messages will include an identifier of some sort, and the error would report that identifier.